# batch file - searching and editing registry?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to search and delete some registry keys. These keys may vary in address, but their names are fixed like below:

```
{1F5093-119-4c0-B05-658A23EC4B}

{C04056-35F-4b8-A3A-9F098E503D}

{978DBB-DCA-42e-B40-6591221CD3}

{CC93C6-D33-4ac-AFA-50075D4893}
```

Currently, I can search for them and write to a new file by command below, but there are two problems, first, It only searches in one directory either HKU, or HKLM or HKCU, or ... ; second, how to write another batch file to read found addresses and delete these keys?

```
REG Query HKU /f {1F7B5093-119B-4c50-B705-658A231CEC4B} /s > "out.bat"
```

If I can read lines in out.bat, the keys could be easily deleted by `[-reg.address]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` loops:

```dos
@echo off
for %%a in (HKLM HKU) do (
    for %%b in (
        "{1F5093-119-4c0-B05-658A23EC4B}"
        "{C04056-35F-4b8-A3A-9F098E503D}"
        "{978DBB-DCA-42e-B40-6591221CD3}"
        "{CC93C6-D33-4ac-AFA-50075D4893}"
    ) do (
        echo Searching %%a for %%~b...
        for /f "delims=" %%c in ('
            reg query %%a /s /k /f "%%~b" ^| findstr /b "HKEY"
        ') do (
            echo Deleting %%c
            reg delete "%%c" /f >nul
        )
    )
)
pause
```